# Display Slack notifications on both screens

Tags: macos, display, notifications, slack

I'm using my Macbook while it's connected to a larger display. I'm mostly working off the larger display. Is there a way for notifications to be displayed on both screens simultaneously? I'm specifically concerned about Slack, but if there's a way to do this for all applications, knowing how that works would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, notifications are always only displayed on on the display designated 'primary'. (The one which has the white menu bar line on it in `System Preferences → Displays → Arrangement`)

Answer (score 1):

You can also move the white bar and make the desired monitor as primary, and receive notification on that monitor.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it, I use Chrome browser, I enabled desktop notifications on chrome browser over mac os.
If I get slack message from any one, now I get desktop notifications on my both large screens and also on primary mac display, so on all 3 screens I get notifications.

I logged in to slack at 3 places, on both screen's Chrome browsers. And also on primary display there is slack client.